# cookies are not getting saved in Browser

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, passport.js, passport-local

I have created a session while user  logged in my application. In login request response cookies are coming. But it's not getting saved in cookie store.

[image: Request responce]
[image]

[image: cookie store]
Can anyone help me on this ?

Regards,
Kiran Gopal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have disabled the web security in chrome. Now it's starts working.

```
chromium-browser --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express-session and http server rather than https, then set the **secure** option for cookie **false**

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false }
}))
```

Comment: can you please share the code where you are setting the session ?@kiranGopal

Comment: var sessionOpts = {
    name: "quizme",
    resave: true,
    // genid: function(req) {
    //     return "wewe"; // use UUIDs for session IDs
    // },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    store: new MongoStore({
        url: config.dbHost,
        autoReconnect: true
    }),
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        domain: "", secure: false
    }
    // unset: 'keep'
}